# Oldest teacher among all teachers (from birthdate)

Tags: mysql

**Display the name of the teacher who is oldest among all teachers (from birthdate).**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Subquery and MIN is one way

```
Select name from teacher where 
birthdate IN (select 
MIN(birthdate) from teacher);
```

Comment: `Max(birthdate)` gives youngest teachers name, it should be `min(birthdate)`

Answer (score -2):

If there is no duplicate
Then use

```
Select top ( 1 ) name, birthdate from teacher order by birthdate
```

Otherwise you can find using min as well

```
Select name from teacher where 
birthdate IN (select 
MIN(birthdate) from teacher);
```

Comment: The question appears to relate to MySQL.

Comment: @Pang when you give negtive vote. Atleast specify the reason. I answered this According​ to mssql server